# Why does pathlib.Path equality operator return true for paths that resolve to the same string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to traverse up the directory tree like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
# ...
        curr = Path(os.getcwd())
        while True:
            # do something with curr
            if curr is curr.anchor:
                break
            curr = curr.parent
```

To my surprise, even though `str(curr) == str(curr.anchor)`, both the expressions `curr is curr.anchor` and `curr == curr.anchor` return `False`, so I get an infinite loop.

Is the right way to fix this really changing the condition as follows:

```py
            if str(curr) == str(curr.anchor):
                break
```

I'm curious to know why the pathlib.Path equality operator works this way, but I'm also open to more Pythonic solutions to the main problem.

Comment: `is` is [the wrong approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe) for sure. What happens if you print the `repr` of these equal-but-not-equal paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curr` is a Path. `curr.anchor` is a string. A string and a Path will not be equal, and will certainly not be the same object.